Can't delete an entities which have related entries in a junction table in Symfony / Doctrine
I have the following entities:
Profile
Tag
TagCategpory
ProfileTag
ProfileTag is a junction table which forms a mahy to many relationship between Profile and Tag.  Each Tag belobgs to a catepory.
I am having trouble removing all tag entries for a given profile, the fopllowing error is being produced when I do:

An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23000]:
Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent
row: a foreign key constraint fails (app.profile_tag, CONSTRAINT
FK_AD2B1EBCBAD26311 FOREIGN KEY (tag_id) REFERENCES tag (id))

Below are my entities:
<?php

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ProfileRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table(name: '`profile`')]
class Profile
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity: ProfileTag::class, mappedBy: 'profile', cascade: ['persist'])]
    private Collection $tag;


    public function getTag(): Collection
    {
        $tags = new ArrayCollection();
        foreach ($this->tag as $profileTag) {
            $tags->add($profileTag->getTag());
        }
        return $tags;
    }

    public function getTagByCategory(string $name): Collection
    {
        $tags = new ArrayCollection();
        foreach ($this->tag as $profileTag) {
            if ($profileTag->getTag()->getTagCategory()->getName() === $name) {
                $tags->add($profileTag->getTag());
            }
        }
        return $tags;
    }
}
?>

And Tag:
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: TagRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table(name: '`tag`')]
class Tag
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 32, unique: false)]
    private ?string $name = '';

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: TagCategory::class, inversedBy: 'Tag')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?TagCategory $tagCategory = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTagCategory(): ?TagCategory
    {
        return $this->tagCategory;
    }

    public function setTagCategory(?TagCategory $tagCategory): self
    {
        $this->tagCategory = $tagCategory;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(?string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }
}
?>

And Tag Category:
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\TagCategoryRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: TagCategoryRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table(name: '`tag_category`')]
class TagCategory
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 16, unique: false)]
    private ?string $name = '';

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 32, unique: false)]
    private ?string $label = '';

    #[ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity: Tag::class, mappedBy: 'tagCategory', cascade: ['persist'])]
    private ?Collection $tag = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): static
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getLabel(): ?string
    {
        return $this->label;
    }

    public function setLabel(string $label): static
    {
        $this->label = $label;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getTag(): ?Collection
    {
        return $this->tag;
    }

    public function setTag(Collection $tag): static
    {
        $this->tag = $tag;
        return $this;
    }
}
?>

And Finally ProfileTag, the junction table:
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ProfileTagRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ProfileTagRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table(name: '`profile_tag`')]
class ProfileTag
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Profile::class, inversedBy: 'profileTag')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?Profile $profile = null;

    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Tag::class, inversedBy: 'profileTag')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?Tag $tag = null;

    public function getProfile(): ?Profile
    {
        return $this->profile;
    }

    public function setProfile(?Profile $profile): self
    {
        $this->profile = $profile;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getTag(): ?Tag
    {
        return $this->tag;
    }

    public function setTag(?Tag $tag): self
    {
        $this->tag = $tag;
        return $this;
    }
}
?>

And I attempt to remove in my controller as follows:
<?php

        $tags = $profile->getTag();
        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
            $this->entityManager->remove($tag);
        }
        $this->entityManager->flush();

?>

How can I remove tag safely, including it's entry in the junction table?

First some advice:
Make in the variables a differents between single of collection naming. This will improve the readability of the code, making it clear what you can expect.
$tag -> returns one tag
$tags -> returns a collection.
Also in your entities like
ProfileTag and Tag and TagCategory, there are some fields nullable. But i don't think there are really nullable. if not. Don't use nullable true and use ?string $name as typing
About the question:
You're creating a custom ArrayCollection with a Tag entity. But your Entity has a relation to ProfileTag
Currently, you're trying to remove a Tag entirely, but if it's linked to multiple profiles, this isn't possible. You would also need to configure things like cascade remove, etc.
I've adjusted your code to the use case where you're unlinking a ProfileTag from your Profile entity. The tag itself will still exist. If you want to delete the tag for everyone, you’ll first need to unlink the tag from all other profiles or work with cascade removal. Personally i don't like to use Cascade remove on this kind of removal/
class Profile:
#[ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity: ProfileTag::class, mappedBy: 'profile', cascade: ['persist'])]
private Collection $profileTags;    

public function __construct() {
    $this->profileTags = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function getProfileTags(): Collection
{
    return $this->profileTags;
}

public function getProfileTagByCategory(string $categoryName): Collection
{
    return $this->profileTags->filter(function(ProfileTag $profileTag) use ($categoryName) {
        return $profileTag->getTagCategory()?->getName() === $categoryName;
    })
}

Example code to remove / unlink profile from tag:
<?php
    $profileTags = $profile->getProfileTags();
    foreach ($profileTags as $profileTag) {
        $this->entityManager->remove($profileTag);
    }
    $this->entityManager->flush();

?>


Hello try to put for the properties  $profile and $tag
#[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: true)]

instead of false in ProfileTag

#[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false, onDelete: 'cascade')] add this to your properties Tag in yours entites, then generate a new migration and check it. You'll see the FK with ON DELETE CASCADE inside
